# How to recreate locally deleted files?

Tags: linux, mercurial

I moved 2 files, since they were conflicting with the latest `hg pull` and I've already done these changes at my work computer.  Now I'm at my home computer, and I don't care about my home version anymore and I want to get the "latest" from the repository, so I moved the files `handler.py` and `model.py` to `handlerbackup.py` and `modelbackup.py` and did an `hg pull`, expecting that Mercurial would recreate my files after the move, but it didn't.

What should I do to recreate my deleted files from the repository?

Comment: maybe duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175427/how-can-i-recover-a-removed-file-in-mercurial-if-at-all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always undo any local changes with `hg revert FILES`.  In this case mercurial thinks you wanted to delete it, and is waiting for you to commit the deletion.

Comment: Thanks" I think that will work. In this case I could actually recreate the file by moving it back locally and then it could do a merge and I could manually work out the merge. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You did a `pull` but did you also do an `update`?  Pull doesn't update your files; update does.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm still learning Mercurial and yes, I did an update and my problem was I don't know how to merge when there is a conflict.