# Can I restore a modified removed file with Mercurial?

Tags: file, mercurial, restore, recovery, revert

I was deleting some files, but I also deleted a modified file that I hadn't done the commit yet.

Is there any way to restore this file?

Mercurial has deleted the local file too.

Comment: It would be useful if you indicated what system/os is hosting your local file. There are OS-Specific ways to recover files that respondents might be able to suggest to you.

Comment: Just to clarify: You're saying that the file had not been committed to source control at all, correct?

Comment: 'Modified' sounds like this was version controlled file which was edited but not committed. There might be a .ORIG file created in the same location.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you commit a file there's nothing to recover from. However if there file was committed at least once then you can use this to help you restore it: [How can I recover a removed file in Mercurial (if at all)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175427/how-can-i-recover-a-removed-file-in-mercurial-if-at-all)

Comment: I know, but why mercurial has removed the local file and not only the committed file? I'm a newbie with it