# How to locate and recover a deleted file

Tags: mercurial, restore, delete-file, recover

At some stage in the past I had a "foo.txt" which was under Mercurial source control. However it has now been deleted.

How can I recover the file when I don't know the last Mercurial revision in which the file was deleted?

Comment: See also [Find deleted files in Mercurial repository history, quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013550/find-deleted-files-in-mercurial-repository-history-quickly) for more about locating it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you know the exact path for the file, you can do something like :

```
hg log -l 1 path/to/foo.txt
```

This will show you the last changeset where `foo.txt` was modified, so you will be able to restore the file from this revision.

Once you have the right revision, you can simply do :

```
hg revert -r <my revision> path/to/foo.txt
hg commit -m "add the foo.txt file again"
```

Comment: I couldn't get your log command to work. It would not show which revision that the delete occurred. I had to do `hg log -l 1 --removed path/to/foo.txt`.

Answer (score 9):

Using revsets:

```
hg log -r "removes('path_to_file')"
```

Where `path_to_file` can be anything documented in `hg help patterns`, including an exact path, a glob or a regular expression.